# why does subsurf pinch weird dent on my chair?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, topology

Weird lines I found in wireframe mode also there's another dent at the bottom.

Before subsurf
[image]

Dent in subsurf
[image]

[image]

Comment: probably an inner face?

Comment: oh my god yes it was an inner face how I was looking right at it sorry

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: An inner face is causing the problem, delete it